# Memory leak with IAsyncEnumerable and System.Reactive.Linq

Tags: c#, graph, .net-6.0, hotchocolate

We are having memory leaks when using GraphQl HotChocolate v12.11.1 and subscriptions.

On a trading app we use HotChocolate v12, and we need to subscribe to multiple stocks at the same time to listen to price updates.

So we are using something like this (not exactly the full code but an overview of it):

```
[ExtendObjectType(SchemaRefs.Subscriptions)]
public class QuotesSubscriptions
{
    [SubscribeAndResolve]
    public ValueTask<ISourceStream<SnapshotModel>> SnapshotChangedEvent(
        string[] symbols,
        [Service] ITopicEventReceiver topicEventReceiver,
        [Service] ISecurityService security,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        return topicEventReceiver.SubscribeAsync<string, SnapshotModel>(symbols, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

where SubscribeAsync is an extension method as follows:

```
public static async ValueTask<ISourceStream<TMessage>> SubscribeAsync<TTopic, TMessage>(
        this ITopicEventReceiver topicEventReceiver, 
        IEnumerable<TTopic> topics, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where TTopic : notnull
    {
        //Subscribe to topics but limit not more than 100 concurrent
        var subscriptions = topics.Take(100).Select(p => topicEventReceiver.SubscribeAsync<TTopic, TMessage>(p, cancellationToken).AsTask()).ToArray();

        //Extract IAsyncEnumerable from subscriptions
        IAsyncEnumerable<TMessage>[] streams = (await Task.WhenAll(subscriptions)).Select(p => p.ReadEventsAsync()).ToArray();

        //Merge streams
        return new RxSouceStream<TMessage>(streams);
    }
```

and RxSouceStream is:

```
public class RxSouceStream<TSource> : ISourceStream<TSource>
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> _enumerable;
    public RxSouceStream(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>[] sources)
    {
        _enumerable = AsyncEnumerableEx.Merge(sources);
    }
    
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        return default;
    }
    public IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> ReadEventsAsync()
    {
        return _enumerable;
    }
    IAsyncEnumerable<object> ISourceStream.ReadEventsAsync()
    {
        return _enumerable.Select(x => (object)x!);
    }
}
```

Can someone identify any possible source for memory leaks ?

We are using System.Reactive.Linq to merge the streams.

Comment: How do you diagnose the leak? How do you verify that the code in question is the cause?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, thanks for you attention to this. We have identified that without subscriptions there is no memory leak. Of course the problem could be inside Hot Chocolate or System.Reactive.Linq but I am not sure if there is some better practise to handle disposing IAsyncEnumerables that we are not following as we are currently cannot spot the problem.

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: `public ValueTask DisposeAsync() { return default; }` should be `public ValueTask DisposeAsync() { return _enumerable.DisposeAsync(); }`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface but unfortunately IAsyncEnumerable is not Disposable

Comment: Try casting it `public ValueTask DisposeAsync() { return (_enumerable as IAsyncDisposable)?.DisposeAsync() ?? null; }`

Comment: Are you running code with  debugger attached?

Comment: Again - please add a full [mre] or at least show how and when topics are created (how often too and where they are stored), how subscription is invoked, may be you should unsubscribe also.

Comment: Seems like your RxSourceStream class needs to implement IDisposableAsync
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync?source=recommendations

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to dispose `_enumerable`.

```cs
public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (_enumerable is IAsyncDisposable disp)
        return disp.DisposeAsync();
    return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: This is working fine but unfortunately did not make any difference to the memory leak.

Comment: Enumerable is not disposable. Enumerator on the other hand can be disposed.

Comment: @eocron The return value from `AsyncEnumerableEx.Merge` does actually implement `IAsyncDisposable` you just need a cast. It's a safe cast, so it's not like it will cause an exception

Answer (score 0):

Two potential places. Either Merge not working and not disposing internal iterators on dispose:

```
_enumerable = AsyncEnumerableEx.Merge(sources); // implementation?
```

or you are leaking subscriptions (subscribe allocates resources, registering delegates in some event pool but you never do unsubscribe):

```
topicEventReceiver.SubscribeAsync<string, SnapshotModel>(symbols, cancellationToken) //where is unsubscribe?
```